# Why is my navigation bar disappearing on my ViewController and then re-appearing when I scroll down?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm not sure what changed in my App. For some reason recently when I'm trying to develop it, the navigation bar on my App has started disappearing and then re-appearing when I scroll down. Here's a screen shot demonstrating this.

What is bewitching my navigation bar to disappear?

**App opens to the screenshot on the left and scrolls down to show screenshot on right.**

[image: when scrolled up][image: when scrolled down]

This is a brand new Navigation Controller that I set up on Storyboard and set at the initial view controller. The actual swift code for the new controller is as follows.

```swift
import UIKit

class NewsViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 50
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Item \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

I do have the following code in the application delegate

```swift
       UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.primaryColor();
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.primaryColor();
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = true;
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary([
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white
        ])
        
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.primaryColor();
        UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = false;
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white;
        UIRefreshControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats because in iOS15 and Xcode13 you need to use UINavigationBarAppearance to customize navigation bar. You need to change your code in AppDelegate as following:

```
    let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    barAppearance.isTranslucent = false
    barAppearance.clipsToBounds = false
    
    let titleTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
    ]
    
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.primaryColor()
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes

        barAppearance.standardAppearance = appearance
        barAppearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        barAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.defaultPrompt)
        barAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        barAppearance.barTintColor = UIColor.primaryColor()
        barAppearance.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes
    }
    barAppearance.tintColor = .white
```